# Is every $T_2$ compact monotonically normal space separable?

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about compact spaces:

> Is every $T_2$ compact  monotonically normal space separable?

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: It would be nice to have some context for the question, as well as a description of your efforts so far.

Comment: I will do! I am looking for the definition of monotonically normal space.

Comment: Yes, that seems a crucial step towards the solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Every  linearly ordered topological space is $T_2$ and monotonically normal.

Can you think of one which is compact and nonseparable?

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the lexicographic order topology is 
compact, monotonically normal and $T_2$ but not separable.